# How can I close a window with javascript for browser Mozilla Firefox version 3.6 to latest 9.0

Tags: javascript, jsp

How to write javascript function to close window/Tab in all major Browser?

```
<form
  name="candidateApplyFrm"
  id="candidateApplyFrm"
  method="post" action="http://<%=sName%>/jsp/careers/jobListingMainPage.jsp" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
  <input
    type="button"
    name="backButton"
    value="Close"
    style="background-color:#245f91; color:#fff;font-weight:bold;" 
    onclick="windowClose();"
  >&nbsp;
</form>
```

JS function looks like this:

```
function windowClose()
{
  var win = window.open("","_self"); 
  win.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did your script opens window?
Firefox 2 and later do not closes window unless you open it with your script.
Try this code.

```
function windowClose() {
  window.open('','_parent','');
  window.close();
}
```

Comment: This function is not working for browser Mozilla version from 3.6 to the latest one 9.0.1

Comment: refer this link for more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close

Comment: ya sure wht kind of help u need ?